# How to pass arguments to composed task from scdf shell?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to launch a composed task via scdf shell. The arguments are not passed to the child tasks properly

Composed-task definition :

> composed-task --graph='app1 && app2'

Command to launch from shell:

> task launch  composed-task-name --arguments "--name=test"

The arguments are passed and executed within composed-task jar instead of child tasks and getting failed. while using the web UI, there is an option called composed-task-arguments which recognize the argument as child tasks' argument.

Composed-task-definition in web UI:

> composed-task --graph='app1 && app2' --composed-task-arguments ='--name=test'

--composed-task-arguments is not recognized in data shell. Only --arguments is valid. How do I pass arguments only to child tasks from data shell ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The section [`Launching a Composed Task`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.7.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_launching_a_composed_task) walks explicitly through the scenarios for when properties and arguments needed to be passed to child-tasks from the Shell.

To pass arbitrary arguments to child-tasks in particular, you'd have to use the `--arugments` property still, but the values would be passed through the `composed-task-arguments` property. Here's an example.

create:

> dataflow:>task create composed-task --definition "t1: timestamp &&  t2: timestamp"

launch:

> dataflow:>task launch composed-task --arguments "--composed-task-arguments=foo=one bar=two"

With this task-launch, both `t1` and `t2` tasks should have received "foo=one" and "bar=two" properties at runtime.

Comment: composed-task-arguments is a property and hence I need to use --properties "app.composed-task-name.composed-task-arguments=foo=one". But I couldn't pass multiple arguments such as "app.composed-task-name.composed-task-arguments=foo=one,bar=two". This [link](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/1502) says it is possible to pass arguments as csv

Comment: Multiple arguments are expected to be supplied with delimiter being a space. So, you'd have to pass them as `foo=one bar=two` instead of the  `,` delimiter. Feel free to open an issue at: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow - we can clarify this in an example.

Comment: The space delimiter is working. But I found a strange behavior.  When I launch the local server and execute the composed task via shell, everything works fine. But when I launch the same composed task for the second time, spring-cloud-starter-task-composedtaskrunner-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar  fails with the error, "Could not find or load main class jar". The start and end time for the task is null in database. If I stop and restart the server again , it works fine. Please advice.

Comment: is it possible to send different arguments for each task? e.g., `foo=one` for `t1` and `bar=two` for `t2`.